# FilesMatch downloading files instead of loading

Tags: php, .htaccess

Rightio...I am about to add an image upload to my site. After reading some security blogs I have added the following to my htaccess file.

```
        ForceType application/octet-stream
        <FilesMatch "(?i)\.jpe?g$">
                ForceType image/jpeg
        </FilesMatch>
        <FilesMatch "(?i)\.gif$">
                ForceType image/gif
        </FilesMatch>
        <FilesMatch "(?i)\.png$">
                ForceType image/png
        </FilesMatch>
```

When I browse to a PHP page it downloads the file.php instead of showing the page in the browser.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

I am working on MAMP locally.

Many thanks
Lewis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I browse to a PHP page it downloads the file.php instead of showing the page in the browser

That's because you have this line:

```
ForceType application/octet-stream
```

by itself, without any condition. That means, **everything** should have the mime-type `application/octet-stream`, which browsers see and understand as binary content that should be downloaded. Not sure how this is a security improvement as it makes it so your entire site can be downloaded and viewed as code, as opposed to any dynamically generated content.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put that .htaccess code in a directory that only has image files. If you don't have your images in their own directory, create a directory for them and put them there (and update any links to them).